# Thinking in English

Tags: learning-methods

The challenge for non native speakers like me  is to master the technique of thinking in English.The ingrained habit of thinking in my native language first and translating the expression(s) into English is difficult to break.Though there is a considerable mastery in written English, it is hard work to think in English on my feet. I seek practical suggestions from all of you.

Comment: http://www.fluentin3months.com/thinking/ may be useful.

Comment: Also check the answers to a [very similar question on Language Learning Stack Exchange](http://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/641/800).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to increase your exposure to English. Watch movies, TV shows,   listen to music, try [lyrics training](http://lyricstraining.com), use a learning method that helps you think in English  such as Assimil or Pimsleur or Michel Thomas. Converse with native speakers. Watch more TV, read simple texts. *Write* in English, only if it's five sentences a day. Practice all four skills (read, write, talk, listen).  Watch [How to learn any language in six months](http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=d0yGdNEWdn0) (YouTube). Soon, you will be thinking in English or whatever your target language is. Speak it  speak it, speak it, hear it, hear it, hear it. Write it, read it. Change your computer interface or Web browser to English.